# Is there a way to define resource directories (not just filenames) for extraction with pkg_resources in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, os.path, pkg-resources

I am going over the `pkg_resources` documentation (https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) and trying to implement an object similar to `resource_filename`, but I just want the resource directory that the file exists in. Do I define this as a default somewhere else, like in `setup.py` or something?

Also, if such a path object exists, is there any benefit to using it as opposed to just an `os.path` object?

How can this package contain methods like `resource_isdir` and `resource_listdir` when there is no way to actually make the resource a `dir`?

Comment: I have found a seemingly hidden `resource_dir` instance attached to `pkg_resources`, but it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation and it returns `None` in all cases that I have managed to use it so far. The mystery deepens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg_resources.resource_filename` accepts directories as an argument -- however, you have to specify the package as the parent directory within your package.